# How to do angular reactive form validation for a number of 10 digits

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I have done this but it does not work

```
'phone': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[0-9]{0-10}")])
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below Regex, to accept only 10 digits (from 0 to 9):

```
/^[0-9]{10}$/
```

With this, you don't need to add minLength.

Your validation will look like this:

```
'phone': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]{10}$")])
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
'phone': new FormControl(null, [
 Validators.required, 
 Validators.minLength(10),
 Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")
])
```

Comment: if you want to the number be exact 10 digits then you can add "Validators.maxLength(10)" too... and if this answer is your solution please accept the answer and make your question productive for others. thanks